# mySQL query optimizer not using indexes

Tags: mysql, index, performance, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7, query-performance

In our production environment (mySQL 5.6.40 on Amazon RDS), for certain queries the query optimizer ignores table indexes and takes several minutes to complete, whereas in our non-RDS test environment (mySQL 5.7), the same queries take a fraction of a second - due to using the indexes.

Rather than immediately upgrading from mySQL 5.6.40 to 5.7 on RDS (assuming the optimizer simply works better!), I wondered if there was something we're missing as the queries appear straight forward... I'm a bit surprised the optimizer doesn't pick the indexes.

Example query:

```
select id, username, agent, app_instance_id, end_time, event_time, 
last_modified 
from event where username='joebloggs' and app_instance_id<>'ad69469a- 
d73f-4b33-a1c5-bde03c765d89' and last_modified>'2018-08-20 20:14:51.394' 
order by last_modified asc limit 20
```

Execution time:

- mySQL 5.6.40: 6m+
- mySQL 5.7: 0.02s

EXPLAIN:

On mySQL 5.6.40 EXPLAIN shows that the optimizer doesn't use any of the indexes (5th column 'possible keys', 9th column 'extra')

'1','SIMPLE','event','range','last_modified,username,appinstanceid,user_app_last','last_modified','6',NULL,'1128956','Using where'

Whereas on mySQL 5.7 EXPLAIN shows the optimizer picks an index.

'1','SIMPLE','event',NULL,'range','username,last_modified,appinstanceid,user_app_last','last_modified','6',NULL,'1030540','0.54','Using index condition; Using where'

Long story short, our RDS instance used to run mySQL 5.5 and all worked fine... but with a forced upgrade to 5.6.40 due to end of life on 5.5 this problem has bubbled to the surface.

I've also run ANALYZE TABLE to ensure stats etc updated for optimizer. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE:

1. Our client app is using JPA, which can be configured to use index hints. Is it simply that the query optimizer is better on 5.7 and that we should upgrade, or should we be providing hints after all.. and not relying on the query optimizer?
2. After running further tests on a new TEST instance (mySQL 5.7.23 upgraded from 5.6.40) on RDS it appears to be hit and miss on the same query as to whether the optimizer chooses to use indexes.

Comment: Could you please add the name of the index that is used by 5.7 so I can add it to my answer?

Comment: From my basic understanding, from the explain it appears to be 'last_modified' which is surprising again as there's also a composite (username, appinstanceid, last_modified) available which would fit the bill as far as I can see.

Comment: Another solution: You said, ther is a composite key (username, appinstanceid, last_modified). Does ist work, if you create a separate index for each of these columns?

Comment: @ltlBeBoy The table already has each separate index. I added the composite later, after noticing a related performance issue with a query using the same columns (select max(last_modified) from event where username='joebloggs' and app_instance_id<>'ad69469a-d73f-4b33-a1c5-bde03c765d89'). The composite worked for this query, but not the one above in the description.

Comment: One last idea: Have you tried (just for testing) to remove the composite key and using the separate indexes only for this query? Perhaps the optimizer sometimes chooses the composite key for this query which does not perform well...

Comment: Don't include `app_instance_id` in any composite index -- it will break the train of thought and not let the Optimizer get to the `ORDER BY`, hence not to the `LIMIT`.

Comment: The query with `max` in it likes `INDEX(username, app_instance_id, last_modified)` (in _this_ order) only because it is "covering".

Comment: @ltlBeBoy - and...  If you have `INDEX(a,b)`, do not also have `INDEX(a)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any system, this will probably be beneficial, probably optimal:

```
INDEX(username, last_modified) -- in this order
```

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see what indexes, datatypes, engine, etc, you have.

The index I recommend

- Is a 'composite' index.
- Is *not* the same as two single-column indexes.
- Deliberately starts with the column tested via `=`.
- Ignores the `<>` as not being useful.
- Includes one 'range' (on `last_modified`).
- It should, but may not consume the `ORDER BY`, thereby allowing it to efficiently consume the `LIMIT`.  Without reaching all the way to the `LIMIT`, it is destined to scan the entire table, thereby taking a 'long' time.

A side note:  `UUIDs` (such as what `app_instance_id` seems to be) are notoriously inefficient when indexed in large tables.  For this query, I am hoping that very few of the rows have that particular value.

To further investigate the "why", answer these questions:

- What percentage of the table contains `username='joebloggs'`. and
- What percentage of the table contains `last_modified>'2018-08-20 20:14:51.394'`

If either of these is *more than* say, 20%, then the Optimizer wisely chose to ignore the corresponding index.  It could be that the statistics on one was better than on the other.  Let's see `SHOW INDEXES FROM event`.

[*Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) for devising good indexes.

Try to avoid index hints -- they may help today, but hurt tomorrow (with different constants).

Comment: Thanks - this works brilliantly and both your explanation and cookbook are clear and precise. :)  The existing composite that includes (app_instance_id) is still required for the max request... so, I replaced both composites with a single composite in the correct order (username, last_modified, app_instance_id) which appears to be extremely quick for both queries. More than happy not to use index hints!

Answer (score 1):

***Edit:***

As commented by user @Rick James, it is always better to try to improve the indexes first before using MySQL Index Hints. Further description for finding the matching INDEX can be found in his excellent cookbook for [building the best INDEX for a given SELECT](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) in MySQL. Also please do not add INDEX(a) if you already have INDEX(a,b).

See [his answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/221204/159079) for a better solution.

---

***Original answer:***

### Native SQL queries

You can use the [MySQL Index Hints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-hints.html) to show the optimizer how to choose the indexes.

### Queries created by JPA

You can use subqueries to use the preferred index first and to reduce the number of lines for the main query.

**Example:**

```
SELECT e.id, e.username, e.agent, e.appInstanceId, e.endTime, e.eventTime, e.lastModified 
FROM Event e
WHERE e.username = 'joebloggs'
AND e.appInstanceId <> 'ad69469a-d73f-4b33-a1c5-bde03c765d89'
AND EXISTS(SELECT esub FROM Event esub WHERE esub = e AND esub.lastModified > '2018-08-20 20:14:51.394')
ORDER BY e.lastModified
```

Comment: Thanks - certainly one option... although I was trying to keep clear of query hints as they require changes to our jpa/hibernate app server.

Comment: OK, then could you please add a hint to the question that you are using JPA?

Comment: @darkmatter I added a solution for JPA. Please let me know if it is an option for you.

Comment: @ItlBeBoy Thanks - it's certainly an option... although currently the SQL is generated by JPA/Hibernate and I'm reluctant to override it.

Comment: After running further tests (see update in question), it's looking like index hints in JPA may be the way to go.

Comment: That suggestion needs `INDEX(esub, lastModified)`.  And it fails to have the `LIMIT`.  And the outer query cannot take advantage of any index for the `ORDER BY`.  The query is almost guaranteed to be slow.

Comment: @RickJames Thank you for the excellent answer! Now I know that I still have to learn a lot...What do you think: Should I remove my answer or leave it (as a "bad example" with the explanation why it is wrong)?

Comment: @ltlBeBoy - My Comment is essentially saying "good Answer, but you left out a couple of things".  So, edit your Answer based on my Comment.  darkmatter may pick between yours and mine to assign "accepted answer".  Or he could dislike both.  You are answering from a JPA point of view; I am answering from a MySQL point of view.  So, potentially both answers are worthwhile.  Keep in mind that we are speaking not just to the Questioner, but to dozens of others.

Comment: @RickJames I modified my answer. Btw., the `LIMIT` in `JPA` is specified by the surrounding Java code, e.g. `EntityManager.createQuery(<JPQL-Query>).setMaxResults(<LIMIT>).getResultList();`

Comment: I don't think I have found a 3rd party package that is not _more_ verbose (counting keystrokes) than raw SQL.